# Проблема при работе с sql.Date обьектом

Tags: java, дата

```
public class ApplTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    int year = 1988 , year2 = 1999;  // Data For Date
    int month = 11 , month2 = 9; // Data For Date
    int day = 9 , day2 = 12; // Data For Date
    Date start_date = new Date(year,month,day);
    Date end_date = new Date(year2,month2,day2); 

    Coupon coupon = new Coupon();
    coupon.setAmount(0);
    coupon.setEndDate(end_date);
    coupon.setStartDate(start_date);
    coupon.setId(1234);
    coupon.setImage("electricity.bmp");
    coupon.setMessage("Hello from coupon");
    coupon.setPrice(32);
    coupon.setTitle("Only for couple");
    coupon.setType(CouponType.CAMPING);

    new Validation().validate(coupon);
}
static class Validation {
    public  boolean  validate(Coupon coupon) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field[] fields = coupon.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field: fields){
            Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
            for(Annotation annotation:annotations){
                System.out.println(annotation);
            }
            field.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println(field);
            String name = field.getName();
            System.out.println(field.get(coupon));
        }
        return  true;
    }
}
}
```

Console output:

```
private long beans.Coupon.id
1234
private java.lang.String beans.Coupon.title
Only for couple
private java.sql.Date beans.Coupon.startDate
3888-12-09
private java.sql.Date beans.Coupon.endDate
3899-10-12
private int beans.Coupon.amount
0
private java.lang.String beans.Coupon.message
Hello from coupon
private double beans.Coupon.price
32.0
private java.lang.String beans.Coupon.image
electricity.bmp
private beans.CouponType beans.Coupon.type
CAMPING
```

При выводе Date информации получаю что то не понятное, кто то может объяснить почему ?

Answer (score 3):

Достаточно лишь заглянуть в официальную [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html):

```
public Date(int year,
    int month,
    int day)
Deprecated. 
instead use the constructor Date(long date)
Constructs a Date object initialized with the given year, month, and day.
The result is undefined if a given argument is out of bounds.
```

Собственно, вот:

> ```
> Parameters:
> year - the year minus 1900; must be 0 to 8099. (Note that 8099 is 9999 minus 1900.)
>
> month - 0 to 11
> day - 1 to 31
> ```

Comment: Передавать по одному параметру ? Из того что вижу там один параметр как мне SET полной даты месяца и дня передать ? Можно пример кода ?

Comment: @Mark.Burkov, вторая часть моего сообщения, после "Собственно, вот:", там описание параметров конструктора который вы используете. Ему нужно передавать нужный вам год минус 1900, месяц от 0 до 11, день от 1 до 31. В вашем случае следовало написать `Date start_date = new Date(88, 10, 9);` и `Date end_date = new Date(99, 8, 12);`. Впрочем, вы уже самостоятельно нашли `java.time` который как раз и следует использовать.

Answer (score 2):

```
    int year = 1988 , year2 = 1999;
    int month = 11 , month2 = 9;
    int day = 9 , day2 = 12;

    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(year,month,day));
    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(year2,month2,day2));
```

Простое решение Использование Locale Date class!

[Tutorial Date API Java 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIg9lNpMJew)